# How to clip image in scale in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, scale

I have a large sized image (2048*2048px), this image is shown as 320*320 on iPhone screen. I want to do this:

In my APP, user can open large sized image(e.g. 2048*2048), the image is shown as 320*320 on iPhone screen, and there is rectangle over the image, user can move the rectangle anywhere within image on iPhone screen, e.g. rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200), then I want to clip the original sized image within the rectangle area in scale.

I tried many ways,

```
UIImageView *originalImageView = [[UIImage View alloc] initWithImage:originalImage]];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 200);

UIImage *cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImageView.image CGImage], rect)];
```

But I got the cropImage is just 300*200 sized image, not scale properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing this, it will preserve the original image quality

```
CGSize bounds = CGSizeMake(320,320) // Considering image is shown in 320*320
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 220, 200); //rectangle area to be cropped

float widthFactor = rect.size.width * (originalImage.size.width/bounds.size.width);
float heightFactor = rect.size.height * (originalImage.size.height/bounds.size.height);
float factorX = rect.origin.x * (originalImage.size.width/bounds.size.width);
float factorY = rect.origin.y * (originalImage.size.height/bounds.size.height);

CGRect factoredRect = CGRectMake(factorX,factorY,widthFactor,heightFactor);
UIImage *cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], factoredRect)];
```

And most importantly if you want to crop image that imagePickerController returns, then this can be done by built in function as below,

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly resize image with size 320*320 using this method:

```
+(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(float)width height:(float)height
{
  CGSize newSize;
  newSize.width = width;
  newSize.height = height
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
  UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Now set resized image in imageView

```
UIImage *resizeImage = [YourControllerName resizeImage:originalImage width:320 height:320];
UIImageView *originalImageView = [[UIImage View alloc] initWithImage:resizeImage]];
```

You can now crop

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 200);
UIImage *cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImageView.image CGImage], rect)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate the scale factor (e.g. originalImageWidth/smallImageWidth)?
If the rectangle is `(100,100,300,200)` in your small image, you should clip your lage image at size `(100*factor,100*factor,300*factor,200*factor)`.